# Retrieving NAT type and external IP address

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, stun

So far I tried using [pystun](https://github.com/jtriley/pystun), but following the manual:

```
import stun
nat_type, external_ip, external_port = stun.get_ip_info()
```

yields:

```
>>> import stun
>>> nat_type, external_ip, external_port = stun.get_ip_info()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 253, in get_ip_info
    stun_host=stun_host, stun_port=stun_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 186, in get_nat_type
    _initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 93, in _initialize
    dictValToAttr.update({items[i][1]: items[i][0]})
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing
```

It looks like the repository is not maintained anymore. I found [ipgetter](https://github.com/phoemur/ipgetter) superfast for obtaining IP address, unfortunately it does not provide NAT type information.

What is the alternative way to retrieve both efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is a problem with `python` versions, the original code of `pystun` using `2.x` and you using `3.x`.

Looking at the [source code line where error originates](https://github.com/jtriley/pystun/blob/develop/stun/__init__.py#L93), we can see that it calls the dictionaries `.items()` method and tries to access its members by position.

Here is the problem:

- In `python 2.x`, [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a list of tuples.
- In `python 3.x`, [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), which cannot be accessed by position, only iterated over.

Short answer: you cannot use the `pystun` repo with `python 3.x`; maybe some patching can be done, or you can just copy and modify the source code yourself instead of relying on the external repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyNAT](https://github.com/arantonitis/pynat), it is based on pystun and support also python3.

It is also on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pynat/) and can be installed with `pip install pynat`.